# Android Volley onResponse & recreating an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-volley

When I recreate my Activity (changing device orientation) and I am waiting for a Volley request response, the code on "onResponse" has no effect since it is running on the destroyed activity.

This is the basic case. To make it easy, I just use "mWaitingServerResponse" as the key info. This works fine:

```
public void onLoginButtonClick(View view) {

        // Store we are waiting for server
        mWaitingServerResponse = true;

        sendLoginRequest();
}

public void sendLoginRequest() {
    StringRequest loginRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    // Store we are not waiting for server anymore
                    mWaitingServerResponse = false;                     
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    // Store we are not waiting for server anymore
                    mWaitingServerResponse = false;
                }
            });
    mVolley.addToRequestQueue(loginRequest);
}
```

Then the value of "mWaitingServerResponse" is remembered with the savedInstanceState.

So when the onResponse is run, it changes the value of "mWaitingServerResponse" on the destroyed activity, not on the one created after device orientation changed. How could I make onRespond act on the new activity?

Comment: why do not you  try to cancel your previous request and make a new request again?

Comment: @mmlooloo I don't want to lose the progress of the already running request.
I have thought of keeping a static reference of the activity itself. This would be used by the onResponse and updated onCreate. However, it sounds strange to keep a static reference to the activity itself.

Comment: I also think that my approach leaks the activity: I shouldn't use an anonymous class for the listeners, but a static nested class instead. I am still guessing anyway, if someone can confirm, that would be great.

Comment: does the server set your file cachable or not?

Comment: @efrel 1) creating a static reference would be troublesome in the case of an activity that there can be multiple instances of. 2) I am pretty sure that it will leak the activity for at least until the request finishes. However after the request finishes I am not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer for other people with a similar issue:

Now I am going to try sending the request from a fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)`. This way re-creating the Activity because of a configuration change (such as device orientation) wouldn't affect it.

To avoid leaking, I think the request should be canceled on fragment `onDestroy()`, and the fragment must not contain any reference to an object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a View or any other object that's associated with a Context.